# ERROR : No "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header is present

Tags: node.js, angular2-routing, angular2-forms

I am trying google signIn using angular2 and nodejs where angular2 and nodejs are running on 4200 and 3000 port respectively.So, when I click on SignIn with Google(button) it throws me an error as:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_ur…d=287790791492-gjuv677chmkmqih4v1p6fc3jti32v76q.apps.googleusercontent.com.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Although, I set headers on Node side...

I followed example on this link - https://github.com/kumartarun/JWT-with-Node-JS

How to solve this issue?

Comment: its a CORS issue, you need to add the headers in your node js app for allowing cross origin support

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Comment: There is express middleware for cors. Have you tried it?

Comment: It's the _Google_ servers that are not accepting cross-domain requests, not your own server. There's not a lot you can do about that (although I don't see how the example code, which is server-side, comes into play).

Comment: @Lazyexpert I used that express middleware still not working.

Comment: @robertklep I reffered same example from link https://github.com/kumartarun/JWT-with-Node-JS

Answer (score 0):

You should add [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) to your nodejs app, something like this:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()

app.use(cors())
```